# How to replace the builtin function pwdcompare in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to migrate a SQL Server 2012 database to SQL Azure (11.0.9222.17). The problem is that in the current project I´m using the built-in SQL function PWDCOMPARE because I store the user password in the database as a HASH value. In SQL Azure I get the error `Built-in function 'PWDCOMPARE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server`. How can I replace this function by another or workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can work-around this limitation by using the raw [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function of SQL Server, which works on Azure SQL Database.

According to [this article](http://sqlity.net/en/2460/sql-password-hash/), it appears the SQL Server 2012 and newer use SHA512 hashing algorithm, and prior versions of SQL Server use SHA1 algorithm. While reading the whole article you will find sample code that will help you get rid of the PWDCOMPARE and actually create your own version of it, thus minimizing the impact on the actual code that calls this function.